# Javascript - cannot read property 'x' of undefined - json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm building a table using information from a json object gained from a url and while the table will build and populate a 'cannot read property 'x' of undefined' type error will occur.

The code for getting the json and building the table is:

```
$.getJSON(url,function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100 || i < data.length; i++) {
        tr.append("<td">"+ data[i].Forename + " " + data[i].Surname + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Workphone + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Department + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td">" + data[i].Office + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td">" + data[i].Floor + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td">" + data[i].Room + "</td>");
            $('#body').append(tr);
    }
}
```

With a basic example of the json being:

```
[{
    "Forename": "fname",
    "Surname": "sname",
    "Id": "id",
    "Workphone": "phone",
    "Department": "department",
    "Office": "office",
    "Floor": "floor",
    "Room": "room"
},
{
    "Forename": "fname",
    "Surname": "sname",
    "Id": "id",
    "Workphone": "phone",
    "Department": "department",
    "Office": "office",
    "Floor": "",
    "Room": ""
}]
```

The error is thrown on the first tr.append at data[i].Forename but will occur at the next data[i].property if Forename is removed.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does data have at least 100 entires? Otherwise data[99] is undefined and you can't get it's propety `x`.

Comment: log `data` to the console and confirm it is in fact the structure you are expecting. Also, you probably want `&&` rather than `||` in your for loop if you are trying to limit it to a maximum of 100 results

Comment: It probably doesn't help that your HTML strings are malformed. Get rid of the second double quote in "<td">"

Comment: Changing the || to && worked. Completely and utterly missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of JSON is case sensitive so calling 'id' instead of 'Id' is not going to work.

Secondly you open quotes where not quotes should be. Around the <td>'s.

Third: Where does the variable tr come from? is it defined above this code, otherwise
you should define it somewhere before using it.

Fourth: Do you want to append to the tr to the <body> tag or an element with 'id' #body. You are doing the latter!

Edit: Added the || && suggestion of musefan.

This should work (untested):

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100 && i < data.length; i++) {
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Forename + " " + data[i].Surname + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Workphone + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Id + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Department + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Office + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Floor + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Room + "</td>");
        $("#body").append(tr);
    }
}
```

Comment: The extra quotation marks are from my deleting class names etc when copying as they'll take up a lot of space and not be useful in finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this one:

for (var i = 0; i < 100 || i < data.length; i++) {
        tr.append("<td>"+ data[i].Forename + " " + data[i].Surname + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Workphone + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].id + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].Department + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td">" + data[i].Office + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td">" + data[i].Floor + "</td>");
            tr.append("<td">" + data[i].Room + "</td>");
            $('#body').append(tr);
    }`
```